# If i have two methods with same name in different classes that extend a class PHP

Tags: php, controller, extend

I have a class:

```
class Controller{}
```

and 2 other classes:

```
class HomeController extends Controller()
{
    public function ActionResult_Index()
    {
    }
}

class AboutController extends Controller()
{
    public function ActionResult_Index()
    {
    }
}
```

If I call $this->ActionResult_Index(); from within the Controller class, which one will be called? Is there a way of defining?

Comment: If you're calling `$this->ActionResult_Index();` then you must have instantiated either a Homecontroller or an AboutController, and be calling it from that instance... it will call whichever you've instantiated in this case. If you've simply instantiated a Controller, then the method you're calling isn't available

Comment: Have you tried it? What happened?

Comment: What If I have instantiated the Controller? will the aboutcontroller or homecontroller simply not be accessible yet?

Comment: If you've simply instantiated a Controller object, then the method isn't available unless it's also defined in the Controller class... classes !== objects

Comment: Ah, I may need to abstract that then. Thanks a bunch mate! Wicked answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you call `$this->ActionResult_Index()` from within the `Controller` class, you'll get a fatal error, because the `Controller` class doesn't implement that method. Parents don't inherit from their children, it's the other way around.

Also: your `extends` syntax is wrong; get rid of the `()` after the name of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Take the following example...

```
class A {

}

class B extends A {
    public function boo()
    {
       return 'B';
    }
}

class C extends A {
    public function boo()
    {
       return 'C';
    }
}

$a = new A;
$b = new B;
$c = new C;

$a->boo(); // Undefined method
$b->boo(); // B
$c->boo(); // C
```

Since `A` doesn't have a `boo()` method you won't get any result (in fact you will just get an error). `B` and `C` will each fire there own version of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Since `HomeController` and `AboutController` extends `Controller` and `HomeController` and `AboutController` contains `ActionResult_Index` and `Controller` does not contains `ActionResult_Index` unless you instantiate `HomeController` or `AboutController` you will not be able to  access `ActionResult_Index` from `Controller`

Answer (score 0):

```
$home = new HomeController;
$home->ActionResult_Index();
```

In the above the ActionResult_Index method of HomeController is called.

```
$about = new AboutController;
$about->ActionResult_Index();
```

In the above the ActionResult_Index method of AboutController is called.

If you have:

```
$controller = new Controller;
$controller->ActionResult_Index();
```

You'll get an undefined method error. The controller class doesn't have a method by that name.